# longtabu and floats: wrong table breaks on pages with floats

Tags: tables, floats, page-breaking, tabu

I noticed that the `tabu` package seems to have problems with its `longtabu` environment, if it is placed on a page, where a float already is placed.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 \\
            Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 \\
            Row 3 & Row 3 & Row 3 \\
            Row 4 & Row 4 & Row 4 \\
            Row 5 & Row 5 & Row 5 \\
            Row 6 & Row 6 & Row 6 \\
            Row 7 & Row 7 & Row 7 \\
            Row 8 & Row 8 & Row 8 \\
            Row 9 & Row 9 & Row 9 \\
            Row 10 & Row 10 & Row 10 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{longtabu}{X[l]X[c]}
        Test & Test
    \end{longtabu}

    \lipsum[10]

    {
        \footnotesize
        \begin{longtabu}{|X[-4,l]|X[r]|X[r]|X[r]|}
            \hline
            Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000019 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000012 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000173 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000011 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.012992 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000031 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000068 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000018 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.029689 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000055 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000004 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 28.276892 & 0.405603 & 1.560010 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.957158 & 0.234002 & 0.702005 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000011 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000002 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000013 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000336 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000004 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000003 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 0.000003 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \tabularnewline\hline
        \end{longtabu}
    }

\end{document}
```

Note that the last table is broken in a wrong way at the bottom of page 1. I guess that the wrong offset for the table break is exactly the vertical dimension of the first table, which is enclosed in a floating environment.

However, I don't know how to fix the wrong table break. I have many pages containing floating tables, but at some places I would like to have long tables with `longtabu`, as exactly as in the MWE.

Can anybody tell me how to fix the wrong table break?

Comment: What do you mean by "the last table is broken the wrong way"? by compiling your mwe with pdflatex I get 3 rows on page 2. What are you getting and what would you expect?

Comment: @ArTourter Notice row 7, column 2 on the last table on page 1. Do you see the "1" inside this cell? This is the page number. Hence, here's something wrong...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There have been some bugs in that area, although I thought they were fixed. If its reproducible just using longtable rather than the tabu version, please

```
latex latexbug.tex
```

and follow the prompts to submit a bug (category tools) although no promises getting this right is hard and changing the code after all this time is hard even if it is "wrong".  Putting `\clearpage` before the longtable will flush the float and ensure things are in sync, although can cause a premature page break of course, but if you need the document in a hurry that may be the best course of action.

Meanwhile I or someone else here may spot a fix directly in your example....

**UPDATE: FIX**

If you apply the changes suggested here

http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools/3512

then your example works as expected.

I seem to recall there was a reason that change wasn't just immediately applied at the time, but I don't see anything in the log, I'd need to investigate, but hopefully this will get you working again.

Comment: Hello David, thank you really much for your quick answer. I have tried to patch longtable.sty and **it works now**. I couldn't determine any side effects, even in a larger document. Would you, as author and maintainer, include this patch in a new version of the ``longtable`` package?

Comment: yes probably, as I say, I just want to spend a bit of time seeing if I can reconstruct why it didn't go in at the time, and also to set up some regression tests etc, but clearly the package needs patching.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle was this issue ever fixed? :)

Comment: @Zero3 not really, you can find some longtable version 5 trials if you search around my github but some things get fixed, some things break and backward compatibility is tricky, so things are as they were for now.