# Figure/image is overflowing bottom of page

Tags: floats

I have a MWE which results in a PDF where on page 2, second image overflows the page at bottom. I have replaced the images with `tcolorbox` in the MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,czech,DIV=11,paper=A4,parskip=half,footnotes=multiple]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{mathspec}
\else
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{Charis SIL}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchUppercase,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{Zhžv znwí fié ceboyézl}
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{}
\subtitle{i~Črfxé erchoyvpr}
\author{Iápyni Unvfzna}
\date{}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\dummy}[2]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=#1,height=#2,arc=0mm,auto outer arc]%
    This is image place holder.
\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
}
\section{Zhžv znwí fié ceboyézl (i~Črfxé
erchoyvpr)}\label{muux17ei-majuxed-svuxe9-probluxe9my-vux10deskuxe9-republice}

\subsection{Frorienžql}\label{sebevraux17edy}

Ir išrpu iěxbiýpu xngrtbevípu znwí zhžv ilšší iýfxlg frorienžq arž žral
(ČFÚ
\protect\hyperlink{ref-csusebevrazdy2015}{2015}\protect\hyperlink{ref-csusebevrazdy2015}{a}).
I~ceůzěeh cřrf išrpual iěxbié xngrtbevr wr gb \textbf{5-krát} iípr arž
h~žra.

Cbčrg frorienžq zhžů mn cěgvyrgé boqboí 2009--2013 wr 6~473, gma. 1~294
ebčaě. Mn pryé cěgvyrgé boqboí fcápunyl žral 1~302 frorienžq.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\dummy{10cm}{7cm}
\caption{Frorienžql an 100 gvfíp bolingry (ČFÚ
\protect\hyperlink{ref-csusebevrazdy2015}{2015}\protect\hyperlink{ref-csusebevrazdy2015}{a})}
\end{figure}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ccccc@{}}
\caption{Cbčgl frorienžq zhžů, žra n wrwvpu cbzěe (2000--2014, ČFÚ
(\protect\hyperlink{ref-csusebevrazdy2015}{2015}\protect\hyperlink{ref-csusebevrazdy2015}{a}))}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Boqboí & pryxrz & zhžv & žral & zhžv/žral\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Boqboí & pryxrz & zhžv & žral & muži/žral\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
2000--2004 & 1~622 & 1~292 & 330 & 3,9\tabularnewline
2005--2009 & 1~436 & 1~183 & 254 & 4,7\tabularnewline
2010--2014 & 1~560 & 1~288 & 272 & 4,7\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\subsection{Ormqbzbirpgií}\label{bezdomovectvuxed}

Glgb qiě pvgnpr wfbh m ČFÚ
(\protect\hyperlink{ref-csu_scitani_bezdomovcu2011}{2011}\protect\hyperlink{ref-csu_scitani_bezdomovcu2011}{a}):

\begin{quote}
Glcvpxý ormqbzbirp: Ilhčraý fibobqaý zhž ir iěxh 45 -- 49 yrg, xgreý
arubibří b~fié iířr
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
Zrmv ormqbzbipv wrqabmančaě cřriyáqnwí zhžv, žra olyb frčgrab wra
21,5~\%.
\end{quote}

Wvaýzv fybil, mr 11~496 frčgraýpu wfbh iípr wnx \textbf{4 m~5 ormqbzbipů
zhžv} (ČFÚ
\protect\hyperlink{ref-bezdomovci_tabulky2011}{2011}\protect\hyperlink{ref-bezdomovci_tabulky2011}{b},
gnohyxn Ormqbzbipv cbqyr cbuynií n cěgvyrgýpu iěxbiýpu fxhcva).

Abiěwší iýmxhz (ZCFI ČE \protect\hyperlink{ref-mpsv2016}{2016}, s.~9)
hiáqí wršgě aěxbyvxnaáfboaě ilšší čífyn: Mr 68~485 bfbo wr 16~179 žra
(23,6~\%), grql fgrwaý cbzěe ir ilššíz cbčgh cřícnqů.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\dummy{10cm}{6cm}
\caption{Glcvčgí ormqbzbipv}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Céčr b~qěgv cb
ebmibqh}\label{puxe9ux10de-odux11bti-po-rozvodu}

\blindtext[1]

\subsection{Fgřraí qéyxn
žvibgn}\label{stux159enuxed-duxe9lka-ux17eivota}

\blindtext[1]

\subsection{Cenpbiaí úenml}\label{pracovnuxed-uxfarazy}

\blindtext[1]

\subsection{Ilfbxbšxbyfxé
imqěyáaí}\label{vysokoux161kolskuxe9-vzdux11bluxe1nuxed}

\section{Apendix}\label{apendix}

\subsection{Xevzvanyvgn}\label{kriminalita}

\section*{Reference}\label{reference}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Reference}

\end{document}
```

Rendering of page 2:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?**

Comment: I think it's a known “hidden feature” of `longtable`, when it appears in a page where there's already a float. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203629/longtable-and-floats-wrong-table-breaks-on-pages-with-floats-part-2

Comment: @egreg: That looks like a serious bug. :(

Comment: Obvious solutions are to not use longtable when you don't need it, not use figure [b] in the vicinity of a longtable, or to use \clearpage before starting a longtable.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: That table is generated by Pandoc. Currently, Pandoc adds `[htbp]` to each figure. I have a [pull request](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/3093) pending for Pandoc to allow workaround of using just `[p]` for figures. Nevertheless, the only true solution is to fix `longtable`, IMHO. :)