# how to avoid overlapping the bottom margin when combining tables and longtables

Tags: longtable

In a document I maintain, one of our tables was discovered to be overlapping with the bottom margin. TeX did not produce any error or warning indicating that there was a problem.

The original case is here: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/1567

Reduced testcase:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{2in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\makepagestyle{mypage}
\makeevenhead{mypage}{}{This is the top of the page}{}
\makeoddhead{mypage}{}{This is the top of the page}{}
\makeevenfoot{mypage}{}{This is the bottom of the page}{}
\makeoddfoot{mypage}{}{This is the bottom of the page}{}
\pagestyle{mypage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{l}
longtable \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{l}
longtable 2 \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
X \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of reduced testcase]

It appears that the problem occurs when a floating `table` environment and two `longtable` environments appear on the same page; the second `longtable` appears to break too late (by the height of the `table`, I think).

What can I do to systematically avoid this problem, or at least to get TeX  to warn if it happens again?

Comment: Did you try addind, sau `[!ht]` as an option for the `table` environment?

Comment: I assume `longtable` starts from the current point on the page, which won't, presumably, include the float ....

Comment: @Bernard Anything with `h` in will do, I think. You don't need `!`. (Though you might in the real document, of course.)

Comment: @Bernard The [table in the original document](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/tables.tex#L163) has `[!htb]`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would appreciate your thoughts on this :)

Comment: @cfr it tries to accommodate floats but doesn't catch them all correctly, I don't have time to check this morning but I expect this is a duplicate I'll find some links..

Comment: http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools/3512

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48280/longtabu-and-floats-wrong-table-breaks-on-pages-with-floats

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203629/longtable-and-floats-wrong-table-breaks-on-pages-with-floats-part-2

Comment: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/master/longtable/ltbugs.html